# Does cargo have an equivalent npm install --save option to automatically add dependencies to Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a `cargo` command that does this: *"I have this package named X, I want to install the dependency, add it to Cargo.toml, and I don't care about the version, just add the latest stable one."*

I dont want to manually add dependencies in Cargo.toml and have to look up their versions every single time.

In Node.js / npm when I want to install a package and I don't care about its version, I use the command `npm install <package>`. This results in the package dependency being installed in the `node_modules/` directory and the package + version pair being added in the `package.json` file under the `dependencies` key. Before npm@5.0.0, you had to use the `--save` option, to automatically add the dependency to `package.json`, on top of already copying to `node_modules/` from the registry.

Rust's equivalent to `npm` is `cargo`, and the `package.json` equivalent is `Cargo.toml`.

Here's what I've tried:

```sh
$ cargo install actix-files                                                                                                                                                                  
Updating crates.io index
error: specified package `actix-files v0.2.1` has no binaries
```

Well obviously `actix-file` has no binaries, because it's a library. And if we have the version already, why not just add `actix-files = "0.2.1"` to my `Cargo.toml` file? The documentation mentions nothing like this.

Comment: TL/DR the duplicate: not builtin, but [cargo-edit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit) adds a `cargo add` command that does what you want.